# How to make items in list clickable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, rendering

What i want to do is make the items of the list clickable so that once i click on one of them it redirects me to another component for example if i am in `/Answers` i want to be redirected to `/Answers/idOfitemClicked`. How can i do that?

Here is the code of my render method:

```
render() {
    const quesItems = this.state.questions.map((question, i) => {
      return (
        <li key={this.props.account.id === question.expID}>{question.description}
          {question.senderID}</li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Answer the questions here!</h1>
        <ul>
          {quesItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML, try having an `href=/Answer/idOfItemClick` in the item you are trying to make "clickable". In this case `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use html link element with href:

```
const quesItems = this.state.questions.map((question, i) => {
  return (
    <li key={this.props.account.id === question.expID}>
      <a href={'/Answer/' + question.id}>
        {question.description} {question.senderID}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Comment: im getting the following error `Unexpected string concatenation  prefer-template`

Comment: @MarwaA. that is only eslint error. You can use template literals for composing href attribute, e.g.: `\`/Answer/${question.id}\``